# Are PATCH shims (.sdb's) no longer functional in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, patching

No matter what I do, I can't seem to be able to get my Windows 10 (64-bit, build 1607) to apply any patches in custom SDB's (as described in the [article of Jon Erickson](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/asia-14/materials/Erickson/WP-Asia-14-Erickson-Persist-It-Using-And-Abusing-Microsofts-Fix-It-Patches.pdf) from 2014).

I'm using Jon's [sdb-explorer](https://github.com/rustyx/sdb-explorer/releases/tag/0.9) to generate a patch SDB from the following source (assuming calc.exe's PE checksum is 0000BE15 and the entrypoint RVA is 0x2900):

```
!sdbpatch
APP=calc.exe
DBNAME=calc_test
P:calc.exe,0xbe15
R:calc.exe,0x2900,CCCCCCC3
!endsdbpatch
```

The exact commands are:

```
sdb-explorer.exe -C calc-test.txt -o calc-test.sdb
sdbinst.exe -p calc-test.sdb
```

The install is successful but has no effect - *calc.exe* still starts and runs normally.

Hence my question - has the PATCH mechanism been removed or somehow crippled in Windows 10?

---

<sup>p.s. I need this for legitimate reasons - I'm trying to patch the touchpad utility which is posting mouse wheel messages which don't work in Windows 10 UWP apps, but the utility is signed with uiAccess="true", so I can't just patch the executable.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From preliminary investigation by Jon, it seems patching functionality [has been indeed removed on Windows 10](https://github.com/evil-e/sdb-explorer/issues/2):

> I've compared apphelp.dll on Windows 7 versus Windows 10. The Windows
>   10 version does not have the function SeiApplyPatch. This is what is
>   responsible for performing the PATCH. It appears that Microsoft has
>   removed this feature.

However, it seems you can [still use shims](https://twitter.com/aionescu/status/790123280409690112), although apparently not on all binaries.